# Is there a way to launch app via terminal in the background?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Is there a command to launch an app via terminal and have it start **in the background**?

Something like the "&" in Linux...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is a Linux too, so a simple example :

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings &
```