# How to launch apps from terminal

Tags: launcher, terminal, command-line

In linux I like to launch the applications from the terminal. Most of the time it is the fast way to launch apps especially on repeated use. In android there are good launcher like **Fast app search tool** will do the job well. But I still interested in launching apps fom the terminal. For that I installed *JS Terminal* but I can't see any app names. Even pressing *Ctrl + T* does't show any app name.

Comment: I too wanted this simple functionality, but rather got this solution using `am` commands in Android. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613889), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5494764), and [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30169/96277) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

> `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n <package_name>/<full_class_name>`

as referenced [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/30102/110347)

For example:

`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.domain.myApp/my.domain.myApp.myClass`