# How to launch a pdf from a terminal?

Tags: applications, terminal, command-line

I gain precious time by launching pdf from the terminal in Linux

```
evince ~/mypdf.pdf
```

What is the exact command that allows me to do that on android?

This [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110506/how-to-launch-apps-from-terminal) gives the following template:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n my.domain.myApp/my.domain.myApp.myClass
```

*How to modify this command to launch a pdf**

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can starting an intent with a relative file name. Better use the absolute file name and use `am start` to view the file:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/emulated/0/mypdf.pdf -t application/pdf
```